# How can I find Conditional Probabilties from dataset points of features (random variables)?

Tags: probability, random-variable, conditional-probability, causality, graphical-model

I am trying to solve the following at work and will dummify for the sake of making it easier to explain myself and getting an answer. My main query is about **Step 4** below. But if something is wrong or missing in any other steps, please do correct me.

My system $\Phi$ has $N$ random variables which are actually real-world data. I don't know the Probabilistic relationship between the data. But I did the following to find probabilities. I want to build a Graphical Causal model from my data. Each RV is the node of the graph.

**Step 1:**

I have binned all the data in some classes for my model. For the sake of simplicity, let's have 2 classes per RV, and $N=4$ i.e. $\{A,B,C,D\}$.

If states of the system are $S_\Phi$, the total number of states that I now have $2^N =2^4 = 16$, such that $S_\Phi \in \{(a^0b^0c^0d^0), (a^0b^0c^0d^1), (a^0b^0c^1d^0), ... (a^1b^1c^1d^1)\}$.

**Step 2:**

I have calculated individual $P()$, e.g. $P(a^0) = \frac{\text{count all events for }a^0}{\text{total events}} $. This way I made a matrix of Probabilities which I can use later when I need.

**Step 3:**

Now I find Independent Probability Distribution with the matrix made above $P(A,B,C,D) = P(A).P(B).P(C).P(D)$.  I verified the distribution by getting the sum of all P()s to be $1$ to validate my code.

**Step 4:**

**How can I find the Conditional Probabilities?**

I know by formula that , e.g. $P(D=d^0|B=b^1) = \frac{P(B=b^1 \cap D=d^0)}{P(B=b^1)}$. But how do I calculate $P(B=b^1 \cap D=d^0)$. Do I collect all the events when $B=b^1, D=d^0$ and divide it by $16$ (i.e. total number of actual events)? or do I  leave $A, C$ from my total events. In either case the $P(B\cap D)$ is $0.25$. Is it correct? It looks so simple to be true

**How can I verify my conditional Probabilities are correct?**

Now, I want to make a Probabilistic Graph from these random variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, if you have $N=4$ binary variables $A, B, C, D$, the total number of possible outcomes is not $4^2$ but $2^4$.

Next, in Step 3 you state:
$$
P(A, B, C, D) = P(A)\;P(B)\;P(C)\;P(D),
$$
which would be true if your four random variables were independent. Note, that in this case, your probabilistic graph is just a set of four isolated nodes without any edges between them. If independence is indeed the case, conditioning doesn't change anything, e.g.:
$$
P(D = d^0|B = b^1) = P(D=d^0),
$$
which is the very meaning of "independence": the outcome of $D$ does not depend on the outcome of $B$, so conditioning on $B$ doesn't change anything.

If, however, you cannot presume the above independence, you need to use the formula you stated. E.g.
$$
P(D = d^0|B = b^1) = \frac{P(B=b^1\cap D=d^0)}{P(B=b^1)}.
$$
And you can ***approximate*** $P(B=b^1\cap D=d^0)$ by dividing the number of events for which both $B=b^1$ and $D=d^0$ holds, let's denote it by $\#ev(B=b^1\cap D=d^0)$, ***by the total number of events***, let's call it $E$, ***not*** by the number of possible outcomes ($2^4$). (E.g. if you toss a coin, you have only two possible outcomes but you can have thousands of events.) I.e.:
$$
\begin{align}
P(D = d^0|B = b^1) &= \frac{P(B=b^1\cap D=d^0)}{P(B=b^1)}\\
    &\approx \frac{\frac{\#ev(B=b^1\cap D=d^0)}{E}}{\frac{\#ev(B=b^1)}{E}}\\
    &= \frac{\#ev(B=b^1\cap D=d^0)}{\#ev(B=b^1)}.\\
\end{align}
$$

Obtaining a probabilistic graph (usually the [Bayesian network](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayesian_network)), is, in general, not trivial. In particular, note that they are usually not unique. You might want to consult libraries that have been developed for this purpose, e.g. [bnlearn](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/bnlearn/index.html). But this also only works if you don't have cycles or confounders.

Comment: Thanks frank. You are right it is 2^N (I'll edit).  And yes, I understand the independence/dependence issue you raised. My another question would be that if my Sum_of(P(A).P(B).P(C)) = 1, it means it is independent and now we can work with dependence in mind. So should I consider that I cannot generate the Graphical model?

Comment: @SJa I am not sure about what you mean by Sum_of(P(A).P(B).P(C)).  But if that means to sum/integrate the product of the marginals over all events then this being equal to one doesn't imply independency. Think of two binary ({0,1}) random variables A and B where only p(A=1, B=1) = 1 and all other events have probability of zero. The sum of the products of the marginals is one but A and B are not independent.

Comment: @SJa As far as your graphical model is concerned: complete independence would mean that you have a graph without any edges, i.e. the easiest case. However, in general, the probabilistic graph (e.g. Bayesian network) will not be unique and you will not be able to infer the causal graph only from observations; you will need interventional data, too. Consult the links in my post and maybe a book on graphical models of causality, e.g. https://library.oapen.org/bitstream/handle/20.500.12657/26040/11283.pdf?sequ